# Can someone help translate 不枉 lyrics to English?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, lyrics

I have a general idea of the meaning of the song. And would love to read the translation.  Here is the lyric for 不枉.

===========

不枉

水滔滔 天蒼蒼

一借東風頃到燒光

樹靜雲淡也是虛罔

撓起弓箭為著射穿怯慌

對酒當歌醉飲星光

相看一刻哪需多講

讓情義竭盡釋放

在那盡頭地方

活著是 生不辜負厚望

又或是 死得轟烈跌盪

用沉著對付兇悍

用血肉成就絕地的曙光

患難是 一起經歷碰撞

在烽火中受仰望

淚流 被遍地花葬

身再傷不枉

Comment: Honestly, I am quite amuse about such trash.

Answer (score 1):

不枉 Not wasted

水滔滔 天蒼蒼 vast water endless sky

一借東風頃刻燒光 everything burn in an instance once the East wind arrives

樹靜雲淡也是虛罔 trees still (no wind), clouds thin (no storm), is all an illusion (of peace)

挽起弓箭為著射穿怯慌 raise bow and arrow to shot through (break) my fear

對酒當歌醉飲星光 in front of wine and songs, drunk under the starry night

相看一刻哪需多講 No need for words, just a moment of eye contact said it all

讓情義竭盡釋放 Let our friendship and affection be boldly and completely  shown

在那盡頭地方 Even at the time and place we end

活著是 生不辜負厚望 'living' is to not disappoint great hope that's intrusted upon yourself

又或是 死得轟烈跌盪 or die heroically and honorably

用沉著對付兇悍 use calmness to deal with fierce (attack)

用血肉成就絕地的曙光 use our bodies to bring first light of dawn (hope)fore in deadly ground (hopeless situation)

患難是 一起經歷碰撞 'brotherhood (in arms)' is to endure fight and conflict together

在烽火中受仰望 be looked upon in battle

淚流 被遍地花葬 dropped tears buried by fallen flower (depict an open sky battle field in the wild)

身再傷不枉 Not matter how hurt my body becomes, it is not wasted